# Why for loop stops at first iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to find the longest word in the array by using a for loop.
But the iteration stops at the first pass.
What am I missing?

```js
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ");
var m = -Infinity;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i].length > m) {
    m = s[i];
  }
}
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this if-statement you're comparing the length of a word with a word itself: `if (s[i].length > m)`. Change it to compare both of the words' lengths: `if (s[i].length > m.length)` and set the initial value of `m` to the shortest "word" possible, e.g. `var m = ""`.

```js
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ");
var m = "";
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i].length > m.length) {
    m = s[i];
  }
}
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below sort option with length of each word

1. Split string by space
2. Sort arrays of words by length descending
3. Pick first element for longest word

```js
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ").sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0]

console.log (s)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KYymjd?editors=1010

**Option 2:** Using reduce method, loop through array once and return longest word

```js
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ").reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc = v.length > acc.length ? v : acc;
  return acc
}, '')

console.log (s)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xePrgj?editors=1010

Comment: While this will clearly work, conceptually it is overkill, an `O(n*log(n))` (or even `O(n^2)` depending on the sort method) algorithm when `O(n)` suffices.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman, updated my answer with option 2 using reduce method and also with better time complexity O(n)

Comment: I think that reduce is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing words to numbers:

```
var s = a.split(" ");
var m = -Infinity; // m is a number
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
   if (s[i].length > m) { // in first iteration, true, 5 > -Infinity
      m = s[i]; // in first iteration, m becomes a word
   }
}
```

...in subsequent iterations, you'll have comparisons like "4 > hello".

Answer (score 0):

because the first iteration if(s[i].length > m) has m = -infinity. then you re-assign m's value inside the if block, so the next iteration you're checking if s[i].length is greater than "hello"

Answer (score 0):

On the iteration, the test is successful, so you do:

```
m = s[i];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
m = "hello";
```

On the second iteration, you test:

```
if (s[i].length > m)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (4 > "hello")
```

Since you're comparing objects of different types, it converts them to a common type; in this case, it tries to convert the string to a number. Since the string isn't numeric, it's converted to `NaN`, and any comparison with `NaN` always returns `false`.

You need two variables, one for current maximum length, and another for the longest string.

```js
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ");
var m = -Infinity; // maximum length
var ms; // longest string
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i].length > m) {
    ms = s[i];
    m = ms.length;
  }
}
console.log(ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need separate variables to hold the length of the longest string and the current string.

```
var a = "hello asdf asdf sdfgfghkkjb";
var s = a.split(" ");
var m = -Infinity;
var longest = '';

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i].length > m) {
    longest = s[i];
    m = s[i].length;
  }
}
console.log(longest)
```